# django query eliminate duplicates

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

In the following  query how to eliminate the duplicates,

```
d_query = Profile.objects.filter(company="12") 

search_string ="Tom"
if search_string != "":
   d_query = d_query.filter(Q(profiles__name__icontains=search_string) |   Q(first_name__icontains=search_string)| Q(last_name__icontains=search_string))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean you want to avoid getting back the same record more than once, you can just add `.distinct()` to your queryset before evaluating it

Answer (score 0):

For the record - .distinct() has some caveeats described in its documentation: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct